# grunt-browserify aliasMapping two levels deep

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, browserify

So I have a directory of files where two of the files are immediately inside the folder:

```
views/view1.js
views/view2.js
```

But one is nested a level deeper

```
views/other/view3.js
```

I want to compile these with `grunt-browserify` using an alias mapping so I can require them as:

`require('view1')`

`require('view2')`

`require('other/view3')`

So I setup the simple mapping in the `grunt-browserify` config:

```
{
  expand: true,
  cwd: 'views/',
  src: ['**/*.js'],
  dest: ''
}
```

The first two files `require()` fine, but the last one can't be found. The alias mapping I'm using is only looking a single level deep. How can I get it to go down every level I give it?

Comment: `**/*.js` should work, could you run it with the `-v` flag? And maybe give us the versions numbers of the packages you are using, including node.

Answer (score 5):

The whole `aliasMappings` option seems broken because I can't even get their mapping example to work out properly. I found another solution that uses [`aliasify`](https://github.com/alexstrat/node-aliasify) (kudos to [byronwong](https://github.com/byronmwong) for [this code](https://github.com/jmreidy/grunt-browserify/issues/127)). This is how my working `Gruntfile` looks like:

```
var util = require('util');
var aliasify = require('aliasify');

module.exports = function(grunt) {

  // takes grunt-browserify aliasMappings config and converts it into an aliasify config.
  function configureAliasify(aliasMappings) {
    var expandedAliases = {};
    aliases = util.isArray(aliasMappings) ? aliasMappings : [aliasMappings];
    aliases.forEach(function (alias) {
      grunt.file.expandMapping(alias.src, alias.dest, {cwd: alias.cwd}).forEach(function(file) {
        var expose = file.dest.substr(0, file.dest.lastIndexOf('.'));
        expandedAliases[expose] = './' + file.src[0];
      });
    });

    return require('aliasify').configure({
      aliases: expandedAliases
    });
  }

  // Create alias mappings with aliasify
  var aliasMappings = configureAliasify({
    cwd: 'views',
    src: ['**/*.js'],
    dest: ''
  });

  // Project configuration.
  grunt.initConfig({
    browserify: {
      dist: {
        files: {
          'build/app.js': ['client/entry.js']
        },
        options: {
          debug: true,
          transform: [aliasMappings]
        }
      }
    }
  });

  // Load the plugin that provides the "browserify" task.
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-browserify');

  // Default task(s).
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['browserify']);

};
```

The `client/entry.js` file now can require all the files that exist in the `views` directory as aliases.

Note that while the above solution works, `aliasify` is no longer maintained in favor for [`tagify`](https://github.com/alexstrat/node-tagify). However, `tagify` is fundamentally different to `aliasify` so not really sure how a solution using that lib instead would look like.

**Update:** After some more fiddling I realized that it's not necessary to use `aliasify` or `tagify`. What is needed is basically a mapping function that takes `aliasMapping` and returns a `alias` array. This is more or less what `grunt-browserify` should do with an `aliasMapping`, but for some reason it isn't working. This is what I ended up with:

```
var util = require('util');

module.exports = function(grunt) {

  // Takes grunt-browserify aliasMappings config and converts it into an alias array
  function aliasMappingsToAliasArray(aliasMappings) {
    var aliasArray = [];
    aliases = util.isArray(aliasMappings) ? aliasMappings : [aliasMappings];
    aliases.forEach(function (alias) {
      grunt.file.expandMapping(alias.src, alias.dest, {cwd: alias.cwd}).forEach(function(file) {
        var expose = file.dest.substr(0, file.dest.lastIndexOf('.'));
        aliasArray.push('./' + file.src[0] + ':' + expose);
      });
    });
    return aliasArray;
  }

  // Project configuration.
  grunt.initConfig({
    browserify: {
      dist: {
        files: {
            'build/app.js': ['client/entry.js']
        },
        options: {
          debug: true,
          alias: aliasMappingsToAliasArray({
            cwd: 'shared',
            src: ['**/*.js'],
            dest: ''
          })
        }
      }
    }
  });

  // Load the plugin that provides the "browserify" task.
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-browserify');

  // Default task(s).
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['browserify']);

};
```

Comment: You're amazing!  Now I get to fix all my paths :-)

Comment: You're most welcome! Please check the comment I added to the github issue. It won't work as expected during watch since it doesn't update the mappings. But if you can live with that it's gonna work just fine :)

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand Don't forget to accept this answer if it answered your question :)

Comment: I wish I could; unfortunately this wasn't originally my question.

Answer (score 2):

That `aliasMapping` configuration is now working as expected in v2 beta.

You can install it with `npm install grunt-browserify@2`

Comment: aliasMapping was removed from grunt-browserify. New option is now [alias](https://github.com/jmreidy/grunt-browserify#alias) which is not actually a direct replacement. Check out Marcus Ekwall updated code, I'm using a similar approach and that works fine.